# Apps to draw on top of a picture or text document?

Tags: drawing

What apps can be used to draw (like with a finger or stylus) on top of a text document or a picture?

What I envision is being able to send a document to the app (or take a picture/scan the document if necessary and load the image) and then be able to sign in an appropriate place with a finger, and then save/email/print the resulting document.

I would have thought something like Evernote would do this, but apparently not.

Answer (score 2):

Skitch (same developer as Evernote) can draw on top of a picture, but not on a document.

Comment: Great suggestion! I can take a screenshot of a document, put it in Evernote and sync with the tablet, then in the Evernote app long-press the image to choose to edit with Skitch. Then I can "draw" a signature on the image (and even type in text over blanks in the form image) and save back to Evernote. So it CAN be done, sort of... but it's still pretty awkward. If Skitch could add to a document it would be great.